# jQuery DataTables within jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

How do I adjust the jQuery DataTables columns within jQuery UI Tabs?

This is my JS code:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
});

$('#myTable').DataTable();
```

This is how DataTables suggests the integration but how do I have to
 customize the code to get working with my click-function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs( {
    "activate": function(event, ui) {
        $( $.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable().columns.adjust();
    }
} );

$('table.display').dataTable( {
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "jQueryUI": true
} );
} );
```

https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

try adding the function to your click event:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).tab('show');
   $('table.display').DataTable().columns.adjust();
});
```

or depending on the datatables version the old api version should also work:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).tab('show');
   $('table.display').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

Comment: It still does not work. For example one column is called Product. The Product Name consists of four words that are all divided by a break command.

Comment: Not sure.. I've used something almost identical to the above with jQuery UI tabs and it works perfectly.  The point of the the column adjust is just to make the header align with the body when scrolling is enabled.  Are you seeing a misalignment?

Comment: Yes. The thead section (the column titles) does not fit to the tbody section (the column values)...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but with the latest version of datatables, just setting `style="width: 100%"` on the table works, no js needed.

The solution is based on the answer from this discussion:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53055/hidden-tables-made-visible-lose-formatting